# The eye comand of Matlab in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

In Matlab I can create a rectangular "identity" matrix by, for example, `eye(2, 3)`. What would be the python equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike [`np.identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html), the [`np.eye`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) function accepts an optional second argument as well:

```py
>>> np.eye(2, 3)
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

You can also do the operation more manually, using a method similar to what [`np.diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) uses. You can't use `np.diagonal` directly because it creates a copy or a read-only view. This method manually creates the same view, but writable:

```py
a = np.zeros((2, 3))
a.ravel()[::a.shape[1] + 1] = 1
```

You can make a view like `a.ravel()[::a.shape[1] + 1]` even in cases where [`a.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) would return a copy using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```py
a = np.zeros((2, 3))
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(min(a.shape),), strides=(sum(a.strides),))[:] = 1
```